# Collect into a HashSet using Java8 stream over a set gives `Type Mismatch` Error

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-stream, hashset

The following code compiles as expected:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test2 {
    String[] tt = new String[]{ "a", "b", "c"};

    HashSet<String> bb =
        Arrays.asList(tt).stream().
        map(s -> s).
        collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
}
```

If I change `tt` to be a `HashSet` the Eclipse compiler fails with the message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<HashSet<String>> to HashSet<String>`:

```
public class Test2 {
    HashSet<String> tt = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{ "a", "b", "c"}));

    HashSet<String> bb =
        Arrays.asList(tt).stream().
        map(s -> s).
        collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
}
```

Comment: In both cases, the `List` creation is completely obsolete. In the first example, just use `Arrays.stream(tt)` to stream over the array elements, in the second use `tt.stream()` to stream over the `HashSet`’s elements. Well, of course, the `map(s -> s)` step makes no sense either…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's expected. `Arrays.asList()` [takes a vararg as argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-). It thus expects several objects, or an array of objects, and stores those objects in a list.

You're passing a single HashSet as argument. So this HashSet is stored in a list, and you thus end up with a list containing a single HashSet.

To transform a Set into a List, use `new ArrayList<>(set)`. Or, just don't transform it to a list, as it's unnecessary.